# Unrecognized font family error in React Native 60

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

here's a screenshot for the error

[image]

react-native.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
    project: {
        ios: {},
        android: {},
    },
    assets: ["./assets/fonts"]
};
```

[image]

I tried to work directly through XCode , but the same

the font inside resources folder and also in Copy Bundle resources

[image]

it's also exist in Info.plist in Fonts provided by application

[image]

I confirmed on everything many times , but always fire this error

Answer (score 0):

if React Native Version < 0.60
You need to tell react native where our custom fonts are located . Adding the following lines in your package.json

If React Native Version ≥ 0.60 (Detail)
Create File “react-native.config.js” and add following code

Comment: Please read my question well , I mentioned >= 60 and already did these required steps

Comment: Yes i see. Are u sure that your react native version is higher 0.60

Comment: @27mdmo7sn react-native link

Comment: Yes , version 0.61.5 - and yes I executed react-native link command

Answer (score 0):

Follow these simple steps to add custom fonts to your app

1. add all the font files you want to an **assets/fonts** folder in the root of your react-native project

   [image]
2. For **React-Native Version < 0.60** we need to tell the react-native where our custom fonts are located. We do this by adding rnpm to **package.json** providing the path to the font files

   `"rnpm": {
   "assets": [
   "./assets/fonts/"
   ]
   },`

   For **React-Native Version > 0.60** we need to create a file "react-native.config.js" and add

   `module.exports = {
     project: {
     ios: {},
     android: {}
     },
     assets: ['./assets/fonts/']
   };`
3. If **npm version > 5** run this command **npx react-native link**
   If **npm version < 5** run this command **react-native link**

This should add the font references in your Info.plist file for iOS and on Android copy the font files to **android/app/src/main/assets/fonts**. You can verify this by opening up Info.plist from the iOS folder and looking for a **UIAppFonts** key

Comment: Are you sure from your answer ?
because the right way in RN > 60 is to have a separated config file

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure about this answer because I am using this in my current project and react-native version is 0.61.5

Comment: it displayed this warning : Your project is using deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release. Please use a "react-native.config.js" file to configure the React Native CLI. Migration guide: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md

and in the end , the same issue

Comment: Could please share your react-native config file screenshot

Comment: Same issue , it's already shared with my post - why you did not read my question good before adding answer